# Moving first element in state collection to the last position in React

Tags: reactjs

Can anyone explain what is happening under the hood as well as provide solution for the following problem? I have a collection of state objects aggregated in the `collection` array. Upon a particular action (here button `onClick`) I would like to move position of it's first element after the last one in the same collection. Both lines, that is addition (spread operator) and deletion (filter) work fine separately, but in conjunction the result is not what I'd expect it to be.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [collection, setCollection] = useState(["one", "two", "three"]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          <p>{collection.map((element) => `${element} `)}</p>
        </p>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            const newElement = collection[0];
            setCollection((old) => old.filter((v) => v !== newElement));
            setCollection([...collection, newElement]);
          }}
        >
          Click me
        </button>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Setting state is asynchronous, your second state update is occurring using the old value of `collection`, overwriting the original update. You could combine them into one single set, to avoid this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is happening because the second call to `setCollection` is using the outdated collection array. In React, `setState` is asynchronous, which means that the state updates may not happen immediately. So when the second `setCollection` is called, it's using the original collection array instead of the updated one from the first call.

To solve this problem, you can use the functional form of `setState`, which receives the previous state as an argument, and returns the new state. This way, you can ensure that you are using the updated state from the previous call to `setState`.

```
function App() {
  const [collection, setCollection] = useState(["one", "two", "three"]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          <p>{collection.map((element) => `${element} `)}</p>
        </p>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setCollection((prevCollection) => {
              const newElement = prevCollection[0];
              const newCollection = prevCollection.filter((v) => v !== newElement);
              return [...newCollection, newElement];
            });
          }}
        >
          Click me
        </button>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Something like that. Let me know if it is good!